# What options exist for isolating a high power DC analog signal?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, converter, isolation

I have a high power DC signal that can range from 0-325 VDC. The source is capable of delivering up to around 150 amperes at 325 volts. I need to monitor the voltage as an analog signal by reading it with an ADC into a microcontroller. I have looked into several options but most that I have seen are transformer based and won't work with a DC signal or they were industrial transducer DIN mountable components that are way beyond my budget.

What options exist to fulfill this requirement safely and cost effectively?

I currently have a working solution but only because I found a really good deal on a part that would typically be out of my budget.

Here is what I have working now:

The analog signal is run into a 50:1 voltage divider using 10W ceramic resistors. The goal of the voltage divider is to reduce the voltage and to limit the current. These resistors have gotten hot enough to turn the PCB dark brown at times. In series with the resistors is a 2 ampere fuse. The output signal is run into a DC signal transducer that I got for $18 but would typically cost $200 or more. The transducer output feeds directly into the MCU ADC input pin.

What other options are available to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide details of your sensor? To reduce power you can increase the value of your resistors, but what is acceptable will depend on your sensor input impedance.

Comment: Which transducer you are using now? What would be the problem of using higher value resistors for less power dissipation, and measuring the voltage divider output with an MCU ADC?

Comment: How about a bog standard voltage divider, current sense via either Hall effect sensor or high side shunt resistor + instrument amplifier and feed it into an MCU? If you need galvanic isolation, capacitive digital isolator from the primary side MCU to your secondary?

Comment: Why are you using such strong resistors? If your voltage divider was based on resistors in the megaohm range, they wouldn't get hot

Comment: What about the DC signal are you wanting to measure? The actual voltage? Current draw? Just on or off?

Comment: Re *"high power"*: Do you mean *"high voltage"*?

Comment: I'd like to see the resistors you were using for the "50:1 voltage divider".

Comment: What is the required precision?

Answer (score 10):

Analog Devices has a large portfolio of isolated amplifiers and data converters.  Many of them include isolated power, so you don't have to come up with a low voltage power source on the field (high voltage) side of the iso barrier.

With these parts, you can decrease the power in your voltage divider by 1000x.  At that power level, 0.1% tolerance resistors are pennies.

Analog output opamps / instrumentation amps modulate the DC signal on a carrier that crosses the iso barrier through a transformer or capacitors.  The signal is then demodulated back to its original analog value:

https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11062#/

If you need the isolated power management at a much lower cost, isolated data converters do the A/D conversion on the isolated side, and bring the digital data stream across the iso barrier to a serial output such as SPI or I2C:

https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11101#/

Another option is to use one of the parts that does not have its own isolated power system for a much lower cost, and add a small, isolated DC/DC converter externally to power the field side of the part.  Of course, if a low voltage supply is possible on the field side, then you can go with the basic iso amp or converter without internal isolated power.

As you drag the cursor down the Part Number column, you will get a quickie block diagram of each part.  This makes it much faster to find the ones with internal isolated power supplies, so you don't have to open two dozen datasheets.

Here is what TI has to say about isolation components:

https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy204b/slyy204b.pdf?ts=1697999852423&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftechnologies%252Fisolation.html

TI Isolated Amplifiers:

https://www.ti.com/isolation/isolated-amplifiers/products.html

TI Isolated ADC:

https://www.ti.com/isolation/isolated-adcs/products.html

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to transfer digital data across the isolation barrier than an infinitely varying analog voltage.  Can be done inside the ADC (which might be on the modulated sigma-delta stream) or after the ADC produces SPI.  (SPI signals are all unidirectional making them much easier to isolate than I2C).

Comment: [Application Note Diagnosing Delta-Sigma Modulator Bitstream Using C2000™ Configurable Logic Block (CLB)](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprad53/sprad53.pdf) shows a TI isolated Delta-Sigma Modulator paired with a TI MCU/MPU with a SINC Decimation filter to recover the measured value from the serial bitstream sent over the isolation barrier. Also shows how fault conditions can be detected.

Answer (score 5):

An easy approach which may be suitable for your application is to use a commercial isolation amplifier. A typical low-cost (< $10 in single quantity) is the Broadcom [ACPL series](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-3563EN). This part needs a 5V supply on either side of the isolation barrier, accepts a 0-2V input and provides a 0-2V output on the other side.

[image]

Since this is a component and not an all-in-one module you do have to supply some external circuitry. It needs an isolated supply (you could use an isolated  DC-DC converter with low power - perhaps 1W - capability and adequate isolation specs), bypass capacitors, and a voltage divider at the input (a couple precision resistors rated for the voltage requirements). Personally I would probably use a 5V to 9V converter and a linear regulator (eg. 78M05) to get a clean 5V supply for the isolated side.

Of course you need to build this in a way that does not compromise the isolation in either the DC-DC or the isolation amplifier or isolation (and perhaps safety) will be compromised.

Answer (score 2):

My go-to would be either a delta-sigma converter (VREF+ADC on mains side, bitstream transmitted to isolated side), or a diffamp with large enough resistors that ground leakage current remains acceptable (10MΩ+?).  And the latter preferably only for type I equipment (isolated side ground connected to protective earth).

Mind the voltage and power ratings of resistors.  At such high values (100s k, 1M+), small resistors will handle the power, but aren't rated for much voltage, and since this is mains-referenced, surge voltage must be accounted for as well.  A higher rated resistor can be used (high voltage types, rated a few watts, are available up to several kV), or use multiple ordinary types in series.  For 1206 chip resistors for instance, typically 4 would be used, so that if any one fails, the rating of the remaining resistors is still safe.  1206 chip resistors might be rated 125V, giving a safe 375V rating for use at 320VDC.  Or likewise for leaded 1/4, 1/2W types, preferably fusible/metal oxide for further ratings and safety.

Power resistors can avoid cooking the PCB by elevating them with ceramic standoffs e.g. [Essentra CER-4](https://www.essentracomponents.com/en-us/p/non-threaded-spacer-ceramic/cer-4), opening a hole under the component, or mounting to the chassis with spring clips, especially for tubular types.  Note that for metal-case resistors, mounting (heatsinking) is *mandatory*, and operating temperatures are much lower due to the epoxy fill (i.e. they have to be heatsinked to the same degree, and for the same reasons, as semiconductors do).

Comment: basically this, but to stay fully analog, I use a comparator-based nonclocked PWM, then send bitstream either over optos or a digital isolator (depending on frequency) and then use an analog lowpass to recover the analog value. The advantage is that you don't get a resolution limit due to an ADC.

Comment: The downside is, PWM is distorted by dependent and asymmetrical t_PLH / t_PHL.  Modern digital isolators are pretty good, but this would be annoying to use with traditional optos for instance. Another pure-analog method is FM, where the transmitted frequency varies within a proportional range; as long as the frequency is readable at all through the isolation media, it can be discriminated accurately. I believe TI used such a modulation scheme, if not presently then in their earlier capacitive isolator families?

Comment: a single opto is indeed pretty asymmetric. But if you stack 2 to form a push/pull output, they become pretty symmetric and also a bit faster. A proper digital isolator is still better though. Regarding FM, I've not done it, but I guess it's a bit harder to preserve accuracy of the analog value (when going for a purely analog modulation and demodulation).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use power resistors to condition the signal to be sent to the MCU (I assume that the ADC input varies between 0V and 5V). Resistors of half a watt or less are sufficient. I show it to you in the following photo:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about isolation?

Comment: There may be no need to use power resistors, but there is a need to use high voltage resistors, proper creepage distances and signal isolation. If the voltage divider resistor was to break down, you could end with an arc flash

Comment: There could be a problem if the single resistor R1 fails short.

Comment: I like that you propose a solution without isolation. From the way the question is written, I have doubts that the OP actually knows what isolation means.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a low-cost solution, and don't need great accuracy, you could use a simple integrator, where the voltage is measured by the charge & discharge times of a capacitor. The resulting digital output signals can be isolated using low-cost optocouplers, to provide full galvanic isolation; this is an important safety-measure when working with high-voltage or high-power signals. See [this blog post](https://iosoft.blog/sia) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The isolation amplifier shown earlier is good and I use them. The problem is that it needs two power supplies. Picture can be found at [TI.com](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc3330.pdf?ts=1698071465281&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FAMC3330).  In this case it only needs one power supply.  It has a built in isolated power supply.
[image]
Note that most of the isolation amplifiers have two outputs!  You will need to measure both outputs and subtract them. In the picture they are using a differential ADC and you probably don't have one. So just subtract. OutP-OutN=output

Answer (score 0):

For cases where isolation voltages are significant but not extreme, it may be possible to use a differential amplifier with finite input resistance.  The basic design concept is exemplified below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLZo7l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each of the input resistors R1 and R3 may be replaced by a series combination of four resistors, with two located near the device being measured and the other two being on the input to the test equipment.  This will provide robust protection against high voltages.  VREF may be any convenient value such that the common-mode range limits of the op amp are respected.  Note that because R1 and R3 are much larger than R2 and R4, the common mode range of the circuit will extend far beyond those of the op amp.  The biggest problem with this circuit is that common mode rejection relies upon precise matching of R1:R2 and R3:R4.  It is, however, simple and (if R1 and R3 are each replaced with series strings of resistors) safe if the common mode range isn't too great.

Comment: Then it would be better for him to use an INA114. from TI.

Comment: @Franc: Differential amps of that style with trimmed resistors are certainly available and would be desirable for many applications, but there's something to be said for having two 1M resistors in series with any sources of dangerous voltages, and two 1M resistors in series with any inputs that might come close to dangerous voltages.  A potential difference of 1000V would yield a current of 250uA when the resistors are working, and even if two resistors in the string fail or are bypassed by a short, current would only be 500uA, resulting in a 0.25W of dissipation in each remaning resistor.

Comment: @Franc: What advantages do you see for the INA114 versus other devices?  One could add series resistance to the inputs so that 350 volts on the input would yield something between a half-scale and full-scale output, but that would seem to negate the benefits of using a precision part.

Answer (score 0):

Charge pump would do it, it will work with varying voltages too.
You could pwm at 50% duty through a transformer and the voltage will go up and down to match.
If you wanna go really wild then you could have a servo motor on the input side to turn a pot on the low side.

Answer (score 0):

Safe and cost-effective solution: opto-coupler. On the high voltage side, you can modulate the analog value of the voltage into a the duty cycle of a PWM. For example, make it so that 325V corresponds to 80% duty cycle or something like that. Use this PWM to drive the LED of the opto-coupler. On the low voltage side, you can use the microcontroller to read the PWM on the BJT side of the optocoupler. The microcontroller can then do the math to associate 80% to 325V. Keep in mind that a normal optocoupler has bandwith of about 20 kHz, so you better keep the PWM frequency at 10kHz or less.